# mb_convert_encoding for russian in php

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, cyrillic

how to convert Russian character to utf-8 in PHP using mb_convert_encoding or any other method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try the following? Not sure if it works, though.

```
mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'auto');
```

Comment: äÁÎÎÙÅ ÂÙÌÉ ÏÂÎÏ×ÌÅÎÙ ?? do you know which encoding is this??
this is a russian translation for "Data has been refreshed.
mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'auto'); not working

Comment: Maybe http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en can help you figure out what encoding it is. Guess it is koi8...

Comment: Please, use some modified mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($str))

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = 'images/да так 1.jpg';//this is in UTF-8, needs to be system encoding (Russian)
$new_filename = mb_convert_encoding($file, "Windows-1251", "utf-8");//turn utf-8 to system encoding Windows-1251 (Russian)
```

now your russian files should open
your russian characters in php are already utf-8
what you need to do is have the name in the same encoding type as your system encoding

or if you need the opposite...

```
$new_filename = mb_convert_encoding($file, "utf-8", "Windows-1251");
```