# simple html dom find returns NULL

Tags: simple-html-dom

Having a strange behavior using simple html dom

```
$html = str_get_html($output, true, true, DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, false);
```

Than

`var_dump($html->find('title', 0));`

returns an object. It's ok

But

`var_dump($html->find('body', 0));`

returns NULL.

I can't understand what's wrong.

```
mb_detect_encoding($output);
```

returns UTF-8 - all seems to be ok with the string.

I increased MAX_FILE_SIZE to 6000000  - it not helps (((

Comment: May be it’s case sensitive then try to use for loop to look for each possible case https://stackoverflow.com/a/2213688/10634638

Comment: @bestinamir  The second parameter of str_get_html is TRUE - that say to the simple_html parser to lower all tags before parsing, I think.

Comment: Try to see if it will work with very basic html page.. How big is the size of the page in megabytes.. If it’s to big try splitting it into multiple files and “crawl” it in separate threads..

Comment: Found that the problem in tags with ciryllic content. But all things is in UTF-8 without BOM. On other server it works perfect.

Comment: Still do not understand. On one server all works fine, on another - not. Both servers uses UTF-8 as mb_string internal encoding. In one server  $html->find on tag, that contains non-latin characters somewhere in it - returns NULL

Comment: You must be getting close.. Since there are different types of Cyrillic like koi8 etc, some may work and others won’t.. May be try different decoding techniques(also checking if decoding worked before passing it into parser) https://stackoverflow.com/a/1623715/10634638

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote `mbstring.func_overload 0` in php.ini and all things begin to work perfectly.
May be this helps somebody else.